# how to use conditional statements to determine font color in PHP

Tags: php

Please i want user balance to be written in red text if balance is less than 10 but show green if balance is higher than 10.

```
     <li>
     <a rel="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="right"data-content="" href="balance.php">
     <i class="oc-partial-icon icm icm-coin"></i>
     <span class="oc-partial-menu-item"><font color="green">
     Balance (<i class="fa fa-dollar"></i><?php echo $balance; ?>

     </font>
     </span>
    </a>
     </li
```

Comment: `if(condition) { // apply css }` - `if(condition > 10)` and the other way around.

Comment: Can you please show me exact code here ?

Comment: you've been given an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <li>
     <a rel="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="right"data-content="" href="balance.php">
     <i class="oc-partial-icon icm icm-coin"></i>
     <span class="oc-partial-menu-item">
<?php if((int)$balance < 10) { ?>
     <font color="red">Balance (<i class="fa fa-dollar"></i><?php echo $balance; ?>)</font>
<?php } else { ?>
<font color="green">Balance (<i class="fa fa-dollar"></i><?php echo $balance; ?>)</font>
<?php } ?>
     </span>
    </a>
     </li>
```

Comment: Please i want all text to be written in red or green depending on the condition but your code is only showing like this http://prntscr.com/8wcrrk

Comment: <?php
if($balance < 10) {
echo '<font color="red">Balance (<i class="fa fa-dollar"></i>' . $balance . ')</font>';
} else {
echo '<font color="green">Balance (<i class="fa fa-dollar"></i>' . $balance . )'</font>';
}
?>

Comment: Bro please i tried this but it didn't work properly, can you download ammy admin so you can come on my pc and set the code i'm coding directly from my cpanel

Comment: My ammy admin id is 50 836 499

Comment: I've edited the code above. Please try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: Bro THANKS ALOT , I'm so happy you could help me out bro .it worked perfectly!! Thanks .. Bro please do you have any Instant messenger so we can chat ..i want someone who can help me create an API for Perfect money .. i will describe how i want the api to function as soon as i hear from you .. I WILL PAY FOR IT ..we have to negotiate though .

Comment: My pleasure! Please mark as answered. Feel free to contact me on here. I have only been a member for a few hours so I'm getting to grips with it still. Failing that - send me an email address some how and I will contact you directly.

Comment: Ok bro , please i want to know if you can create a perfect money api that verifies user's perfect money e-voucher number and activation code and adds it automatically to their balance . or verifies batch payment to a certain perfect money account number and automatically add balance to user's account ..  you can check http://shields.su/recharge/pm to see how the e-voucher system works and also check http://inb0x.ru/perfect_money.php to see how the batch system works..Please get back to me asap ..Please get back to me asap ..